# Laravel LeftJoin where

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have some problems with my eloquent model, where I try to join two different tables in one

Now I have two tables like.

First tables name "company_saved_cv"

```
|id|company_id|worker_id |
--------------------------
|1|       2    |  61     |
|3|       3    |  66     |
|4|       2    |  69     |
--------------------------
```

Second tables name "workers"

```
|id|location|name_and_surname|
------------------------------
|61|London  | John John      |
|62|London  | John John      |
|66|London  | John John      |
|67|London  | John John      |
|68|London  | John john      |
```

And I whana get table like this.

```
|id|location|name_and_surname|worker_id|
---------------------------------------|
|61|London  | John John      |  61     |
|62|London  | John John      | NULL    |
|66|London  | John John      | 66      |
|67|London  | John John      | NULL    |
|68|London  | John john      | NULL    |
```

where is my model function

```
public static  function CvSearch($interested_field, $location)
{

    $match = "MATCH( `interested_fields`) AGAINST (?)";

    $query = Worker::select('workers.name_and_surname', 'workers.id', 'workers.location','company_saved_cv.worker_id')
        ->leftJoin('company_saved_cv', function($leftJoin)
        {
            $leftJoin->on('company_saved_cv.worker_id', '=', 'workers.id')
                ->where('company_saved_cv.company_id', '=', Session::get('company_id') );


        })
        ->where('workers.location', '=', $location)
        ->whereRaw($match, array($interested_field))
        ->orderBy('workers.created_at')
        ->paginate(10);
    return $query;
}
```

If I comment this line:`->where('company_saved_cv.company_id', '=', Session::get('company_id') );` It is working, but I need get only rows from workers table where company_id = 2 (in my example);

```
Session::get('company_id') = 2
```

I will check it by logging it in laravel.log file.

I fink it is problem with where('company_saved_cv.company_id', '=', Session::get('company_id') ); request, but I can't figure it out, maybe some one can help me?

Comment: What is your logic to achieve the result. Because i cant see any kind of Relation b/w your tables.

Comment: Smells like an XY problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solve this problem with this code

```
 $query = Worker::select('workers.name_and_surname', 'workers.id', 'workers.location','company_saved_cv.worker_id')
        ->leftJoin('company_saved_cv', function($leftJoin)use($company_id)
        {
            $leftJoin->on('workers.id', '=', 'company_saved_cv.worker_id');
            $leftJoin->on(DB::raw('company_saved_cv.company_id'), DB::raw('='),DB::raw("'".$company_id."'"));


        })
```

Comment: You don't need to use `DB::raw` on the second argument (`=`).

Comment: You don't need to use it on the first argument either.

Comment: You should cast `$company_id` to an integer too, to make sure you're safe injections and that kind of nasty stuff. `DB::raw("'" . (int) $company_id . "'")`

Comment: Thanks, It is very usefull when you want to add join with where clause.

Comment: This is an SQL Injection though. You're putting the company ID into the query without sanitation.

Answer (score 3):

Well when you use LEFT JOIN with where it acts as an INNER JOIN

**Use LEFT JOIN and WHERE like**

```
SELECT workers.name_and_surname, workers.id, workers.location,company_saved_cv.worker_id
FROM workers LEFT JOIN company_saved_cv
ON company_saved_cv.worker_id= workers.id
WHERE company_saved_cv.company_id = 2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|id|location|name_and_surname|worker_id|
---------------------------------------|
|61|London  | John John      |  61     |
|66|London  | John John      |  66     |
```

**Use LEFT JOIN and AND like**

```
SELECT workers.name_and_surname, workers.id, workers.location,company_saved_cv.worker_id
FROM workers LEFT JOIN company_saved_cv
ON company_saved_cv.worker_id= workers.id
AND company_saved_cv.company_id = 2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|id|location|name_and_surname|worker_id|
---------------------------------------|
|61|London  | John John      |  61     |
|62|London  | John John      | NULL    |
|66|London  | John John      | 66      |
|67|London  | John John      | NULL    |
|68|London  | John john      | NULL    |
```

New query

```
$query = Worker::select('workers.name_and_surname', 'workers.id', 'workers.location','company_saved_cv.worker_id')
        ->leftJoin('company_saved_cv', function($leftJoin)
        {
            $leftJoin->on('company_saved_cv.worker_id', '=', 'workers.id')

                ->on('company_saved_cv.company_id', '=', Session::get('company_id') );


        })
```

Comment: @lggg3: It should help.

Comment: I got the error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::and()

Comment: just a little issue with syntax, now check.

Comment: I already tried it, it didin't work, i wrote the correct answer down

Answer (score 3):

More or less like this:

```
$directoryTypeId = 1;

Node::query()
    ->leftJoin('directories', 'directories.id', '=', 'nodes.directory_id')
    ->leftJoin('directory_types', function ($leftJoin) use ($directoryTypeId) {
        $leftJoin
            ->on('directory_types.id', '=', DB::raw($directoryTypeId))
            ->on('directory_types.COLUMN_1', '=', 'directories.COLUMN_2');
    })
    ->select([
        'nodes.id as node_id',
        'directories.name',
        'directory_types.id as type_id',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the Model for it. The last table, you can remove the location because you can get it with and from the model. Create easily a many-2-many relationship or something you want. Check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships