# Laravel Eloquent using WHERE instead of AND in Joins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
select i.name,i.id itemId,its.item_id from items i
LEFT JOIN items_subscribers its
ON i.id = its.item_id
and its.user_id = 1
```

Which I transformed into Eloquent Way like this:

```
$records = Item::where('items_subscribers.user_id',$user_id)
            ->leftJoin('items_subscribers','items.id','=','items_subscribers.item_id')
            ->select(['items.name','items.id','items_subscribers.item_id as selected_item_id'])->get();
```

When I run `print_r(DB::getQueryLog());` it prints following query:

```
select `items`.`name`, `items`.`id`, `items_subscribers`.`item_id` as `selected_item_id` from `items` left join `items_subscribers` on `items`.`id` = `items_subscribers`.`item_id` where `items_subscribers`.`user_id` = ?
```

The query yields nothing. I want to use AND instead of WHERE. How'd I do this?

I am using Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a closure and adding the condition in there:

```
$records = Item::leftJoin('item_subscribers', function($join) use ($user_id){
        $join->on('items.id','=','items_subscribers.item_id');
        $join->where('items_subscribers.user_id', '=', $user_id);
    })
    ->select(['items.name','items.id','items_subscribers.item_id as selected_item_id'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Perfect. Just wondering Why `andWhere` can't work and one has to call closure anyway?

Comment: Well the `where()` inside the join closure is a different `where()` than the one outside. The "join-where" will add an additional `on` clause but use a binding for the value. If you'd use `on()` twice it would search for a column named `1` (the `$user_id`). Hope that explanation helps ;)

Comment: A weird issue. I am not being able to access columns of JOINed table `items_subscribers`. Output shown here: http://pastebin.com/i4mk7P0z

Comment: How are you trying to access them?

Comment: I just `print_r($records)`, the column `selected_item_id` is empty

Comment: Just to be sure, try `$records->first()->selected_item_id` before we investigate more ;)

Comment: it prints nothig. If you visit pastebin link you will find that key has no value in it.

Comment: Since the output of you posted on pastebin is obviously not the result of this exact query I'm not sure if I can help you. Is it possible the the item just has no matching entry in `item_subscribers`?

Comment: There re atleast 2 records match the criteria having value `1` and `2`. Rest are `NULL`. The whole dump of `$records` is here http://pastebin.com/xvKbw8d5

Comment: You could try to do `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and run the query in a DB tool. (Replace `?` with the user id)

Comment: You were dead right. The entire column is null. But why is it not yielding original SQL query I pasted inQuestion? It formed query: **select `items`.`name`, `items`.`id`, `items_subscribers`.`item_id` as `selected_id`, `items`.`image`, `items`.`waiting`, `items`.`availability_date` from `items` left join `items_subscribers` on `items`.`id` = `items_subscribers`.`item_id` and `items_subscribers`.`user_id` = ?**

Comment: For me that looks pretty much the same as the query in your question... What am I missing?

Comment: I am not getting any clue either.  I ran this query on SQL client and it returned same NULL column

Comment: What if you run it without the `user_id` part?

Comment: oh yeah it runs fine then

Comment: And do you have data filled in for `user_id` in your table?

Comment: Yes becuase Query in Question runs perfect

Comment: And if you take the query from the builder and replace `?` with `1` it doesn't work?

Comment: The query generated by the builder is not working at all

Comment: Found out. The page calling this query, it also runs another query which was setting user_id to 0 hence returning column NULL. I am sorry that I took your time and it was all my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `on` method at the `leftJoin` part instead of using the `where` method. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26714765/3208719

Comment: doing this gives this error now `Database [items_subscribers.user_id] not configured.`