# How to join two tables and get id from first table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to join `posts` and `tags` tables and get id of `posts` table, but this code giving me id (11) of `tags` table, but the post id is 15.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wconw.png)

```
$posts = Post::leftJoin('tags', 'tags.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
                ->where('tags.slug', $slug)->get();

 dd($posts);
```

Table tags

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
    $table->string('tag');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->integer('views')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Table posts

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('admin_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->integer('views')->default(0);
    $table->longText('content');
    $table->text('meta_keywords')->nullable();
    $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
    $table->enum('is_home', ['0', '1',])->default('1');
    $table->enum('is_featured', ['0', '1',])->default('0');
    $table->enum('is_slider', ['0', '1',])->default('0');
    $table->integer('slider_order')->default(0);
    $table->enum('type', ['Article', 'Video']);
    $table->enum('status', ['Visible', 'Invisible', 'Draft', 'Pending']);
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Model tag

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_id', 'tag', 'slug',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Model posts

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this `Post::select('posts.*', 'tags.*')->leftJoin('tags', function($leftJoin) { $leftJoin->on('tags.post_id', '=', 'posts.id'); })->get();`

Comment: Not working! Giving same result.

Comment: Could you post your `toSql()` result?

Comment: Check image i already included with post.

Comment: I mean the sql string result. not $posts result

Comment: And you should post your table structure, you should not just post your code and result.

Comment: What is toSql() result?

Comment: Updated my post with table structure and models.

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql

Comment: Have you check your database data? your id is pk, your id will not same with post_id.

Comment: But there are another table joined by same structure & query and that's works, anyway what is the solution now? I don't understand what you talking about and what is pk, and which id will not same with post_id?

Comment: I mean maybe is your data problem, and you should dump the sql string and just execute the sql on the postgres.

Comment: And you just post your code, I don't know what you want. You should reference this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711573/laravel-leftjoin-where

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 $posts = Post::leftJoin('tags', 'tags.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
           ->select('tags.id as tag_id','posts.*')
           ->where('tags.slug','=', $slug)
           ->get();
```

Now `$posts->id` will be `id` of `posts` table.`$posts->tag_id` will be the `id` of `tags` table.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation now to do this, i will mark it later.